matplotlib animation aren't shown
When i try to run the matplotlib animation notebook animate_decay.ipynb from  matplotlib.org, all i get is an empty figure: axes and a grid, but no line object which changes. There are no errors displayed.
Other notebooks with matplotlib animations behave in the same way.
I tried animate_decay.ipynb on a windows machine as well as on a linux machine - the behaviour was the same in both cases (the empty figure with grid).
Is there some setting in jupyter i need to change, or is there a python package required for animations to be animated?
EDIT: also the simple script "animation_demo" `
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)
data = np.random.random((50, 50, 50))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for i, img in enumerate(data):
    ax.clear()
    ax.imshow(img)
    ax.set_title(f"frame {i}")
    # Note that using time.sleep does *not* work here!
    plt.pause(0.1)`

does not work properly: it only displays frame 0 and stops.

Ideally, for a question like this, you need to share your specific version and flavor of Jupyter in the post. There's three current versions in play right now and a lot of older ones. Animations are quite complex and so they need special considerations that depend on the tech and specific versions.

Please stick with one question & topic per post. Your posted code block looks nothing like the example in animate_decay.ipynb (from here) that uses ani = animation.FuncAnimation(). I'm going to only address that since it most of what you talk about and then bring up some other '"animation_demo', without a link.

So far I couldn't find a version using ax.clear() that was complete and worked. The notebook I reference there has animations that don't need animation.FuncAnimation() but not one that includes ax.clear(). Maybe the approaches there could be adapted. Or maybe you know of a more complete example that you can link to?

Assuming you have fairly modern tech for editing and running Jupyter Notebook files, what is going on is described in bullet point #1 in my answer here.
I'll summarize things here and show you the animate_decay plot code and how it works with it...
These days you need to install and use ipympl for most animations.
Install ipympl and use with %matplotlib ipympl in modern JupyterLab and Jupyter Notebook 7+, see here for more details. (Despite the current documentation not containing an example for plots for Matplotlib's animation.FuncAnimation(), it is considered one of the 'interactive' features of Matplotlib.)
To use it, it would be like this AFTER INSTALLING for code in animate_decay.ipynb from here:
%matplotlib ipympl
import itertools

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import matplotlib.animation as animation


def data_gen():
    for cnt in itertools.count():
        t = cnt / 10
        yield t, np.sin(2*np.pi*t) * np.exp(-t/10.)


def init():
    ax.set_ylim(-1.1, 1.1)
    ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
    del xdata[:]
    del ydata[:]
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)
    return line,

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)
ax.grid()
xdata, ydata = [], []


def run(data):
    # update the data
    t, y = data
    xdata.append(t)
    ydata.append(y)
    xmin, xmax = ax.get_xlim()

    if t >= xmax:
        ax.set_xlim(xmin, 2*xmax)
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
    line.set_data(xdata, ydata)

    return line,

# Only save last 100 frames, but run forever
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, run, data_gen, interval=100, init_func=init,
                              save_count=100)
plt.show()

The only change in that from what is found in animate_decay.opynb is the first line. You need to invoke the correct backend.
I just ran that code block in a new notebook in a session launched from here where ipympl is already installed in the sessions that launch and it worked great.
